# AngularJs passing button id to modal dialog

Tags: angularjs, modal-dialog, angular-ui-router

Please help me, I would like to pass button id to a modal dialog using AngularJS.

The modal dialog was opened by the button itself.

Here is my code :

**Button :**

```
<button ui-sref=".modal"  id='{{data.nip}}'  data-ng-click="simulate(data.nip)">Simulasi</button>
```

**Modal Dialog :**

```
  <div class="modal-overlay fade">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <h2>Modal</h2>
      This modal has a substate.  <a ui-sref=".substate">Activate it</a>
      <div ui-view='modal'></div>
      <a ui-sref="app">{{nip}}</a>
    </div>
  </div>
```

**ui.route state :**

```
         .state('masterpegawai.alltalenta.modal', {
            url: '/modal',
            views:{
              "modal": {
                controller: showAlert,
              }
            }
         })

    var simulate= function ($scope, $modal, $log, nip) {



    var modalInstance = $modal.open({
        templateUrl: 'public/js/modal.html',
        controller: ModalInstanceCtrl,
        resolve: {
            nip: function () {

                    return nip;

            }
        }
    });
    }

var ModalInstanceCtrl = function ($scope, $modalInstance, nip) {
    $scope.nip = nip;
    console.log($scope.params)
};
```

Comment: Haven't used this particular setup before, but can you add a resolve to your modal state: resolve: { nip:  function() { return $scope.data.nip; } }... Then pass nip as a parameter into your controller function and access it that way? (Sorry for formatting, on mobile)

Comment: How to pass the nip from simulate(data.nip) ? I have update my code

Comment: I might not fully have the picture of what you're trying to do, but if it's the `simulate` function that opens the modal, then you would replace `showAlert` with `simulate`, so it would be something like: `var simulate = function(nip) { var modalInstance = $modal.open({....resolve: { nip: function() { return nip; } } };`, because you're passing in the `$scope.data.nip` value in your html.

Comment: I got error : Error: [$injector:unpr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.4/$injector/unpr?p0=nipProvider%20%3C-%20nip